# Use an array within itself in php

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible to use array for internal like this?

```
$b = array(
  'a' => 'Adam',
  'b' => $b['a'].' and eve'
);
```

Comment: No, it's not, because `$b` won't be defined yet.

Comment: If you turned on any amount of error messaging you would get `NOTICE Undefined variable: b on line number 5` pretty simple

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible, what you can do is this:

```
$b = array(
    'a' => 'Adam'
);

$b['b'] = $b['a'] . ' and eve';
```

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible because the array $b hasn't been created yet when you try to add

```
'b' => $b['a'];
```

Instead you should create the array $b, then add the other element. Like so:

```
$b = array('a' => 'Adam');
$b['b'] = $b['a'] . ' and eve';
```

Answer (score 0):

No not possible, as doing so would produce **E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: b -- at line X** _where X is the where you are `'b' => $b['a']` assigning a value to `b`

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not possible, It will give Error like "Undefined variable: b". If you want to perform anyway, use this one

$b = array('a' => 'Adam');
$b['b'] = $b['a'];